# How to search a text file and save searched data in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a text file with various lines and information in it.  I would like to search for a specific word in that text file and save it to my database.

So for example this is some of the content in my text file:

```
'intProvinceId' => '1', 
'strName' => 'Eastern Cape', 
'intProvinceId' => '2', 
'strName' => 'Free State', 
'intProvinceId' => '3', 
'strName' => 'Gauteng', 
'intProvinceId' => '4', 
'strName' => 'Kwazulu-Natal', 
'intProvinceId' => '5', 
'strName' => 'Mpumalanga', 
'intProvinceId' => '6', 
'strName' => 'Northern Cape', 
'intProvinceId' => '7', 
'strName' => 'Limpopo', 
'intProvinceId' => '8', 
'strName' => 'North West Province', 
'intProvinceId' => '9', 
'strName' => 'Western Cape',
```

And this is the code I am using to search for the text and save it in my database:

```
<?php
    $search1 = "intProvinceId";     
$search2 = "strName";
$lines = file('provinces.txt'); 
    foreach($lines as $line) 
        { 
        if(stristr($line,$search1) || stristr($line,$search2))
            echo " $line <br>"; 
        } 
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "axxess");
    $query = "INSERT INTO provinces(province_id, name) VALUES('$search1', 
'$search2')"; 

    if(!mysqli_query($connect,$query)) 
    { 
        die('Error : Query Not Executed. Please Fix the Issue! ' . 
mysqli_error($connect)); } 
else
 { 
echo "Data Inserted Successully!!!"; 
}
?>
```

It does save `intProvinceId` and `strName` in my database but not the corresponding text.  I would to save only the `intProvinceId` value and the `strName1` value in my database so that it looks like this in my table:

```
-------------------------------------
|id    | province_id | name         | 
-------------------------------------
| 1    | 1           | Eastern Cape |
-------------------------------------
| 2    | 2           | Free State   |
-------------------------------------

etc
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you show all the content of the file? You could replace `=>` with `:` to transform it into a `json`.

Comment: thats pretty much all of it.  it has a few more lines above and below it with different values